# Changing the text of a button when clicking an attribute in the dropdown of it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown button, when entering the webpage the button says "Select Region". If you hover over that button you get different regions.

The main value of the button needs to change when they click the region they want.

Also I want the button to be within the search bar on the right side, but it's always placing it underneath it like you can see in the example. I've tried a lot of different options, but I cannot get this fixed.

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: url(../images/background/body_background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo img{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.SearchSummoners {
  margin: auto;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid;

  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.region_dropdown_section {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.region_dropdown_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.region_dropdown_content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.region_dropdown_content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .region_dropdown_content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.Searchbox_Summoners {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
}

#SearchBox{
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left:  10%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 40px;;
 }

#SearchInput{
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
 }
```

```html
<?php define('DeniedAccessFiles', TRUE); ?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="logo">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&txt=500%C3%97225&w=500&h=225">
</div>
  <div class="SearchSummoners">
    <div id="SearchBox">
      <form method="POST">
        <input id="SearchInput" value="Enter the Summoner Name"  onfocus="if(this.value  == 'Enter the Summoner Name') { this.value = ''; } " onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter the Summoner Name'; }"  type="text" name="SummonerName"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="region_dropdown_section">
      <button class="dropbtn">Select Region</button>
      <div class="region_dropdown_content">
        <a href="#">North America</a>
        <a href="#">Europe West</a>
        <a href="#">Europe NE</a>
        <a href="#">Korea</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: you need solution in JavaScript or jquery ?

Comment: Well I used the solution from @Ivan Karaman. But there is a bug now. 

Whenever I click a region, it changes, but when I click outside of the button then, the region removes and the button just becomes empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to links click trigger and onclick change button text...

**UPDATE: fixed empty button text**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var regionDropDown = $('.region_dropdown_section'),
      regionButton = regionDropDown.find('button'),
      regionList = regionDropDown.find('.region_dropdown_content').children();
  
  $(regionList).on('click', function(e){
    var region = e.target;
    regionButton.text(region.text).val(region.text);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: url(../images/background/body_background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo img{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.SearchSummoners {
  margin: auto;
  width: 55%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid;

  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.region_dropdown_section {
    display: inline-block;
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.region_dropdown_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.region_dropdown_content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.region_dropdown_content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .region_dropdown_content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.Searchbox_Summoners {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
}

#SearchBox{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left:  10%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 40px;;
 }

#SearchInput{
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php define('DeniedAccessFiles', TRUE); ?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="logo">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&txt=500%C3%97225&w=500&h=225">
</div>
  <div class="SearchSummoners">
    <div id="SearchBox">
      <form method="POST">
        <input id="SearchInput" value="Enter the Summoner Name"  onfocus="if(this.value  == 'Enter the Summoner Name') { this.value = ''; } " onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter the Summoner Name'; }"  type="text" name="SummonerName"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="region_dropdown_section">
      <button class="dropbtn">Select Region</button>
      <div class="region_dropdown_content">
        <a href="#">North America</a>
        <a href="#">Europe West</a>
        <a href="#">Europe NE</a>
        <a href="#">Korea</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Hello
This worked amazing for me already. Now I have 2 more problems with this.

After clicking a region and going away, sometimes the button gets blank and empty. Also the size of the button keeps changing, is it possible to have that 1 standard size, so it doesn't change sizes when selecting a region with smaller text.

How would I then go about putting the dropdown in the searchbox on the right side? I've tried this ,but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be:

for each anchor under the div with class region_dropdown_content attach the click event handler. Inside this handler change the value of your field according to the user selection.

The solution can be implemented in jQuery as well as in javascript.

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('div.region_dropdown_content a').on('click', function(e) {
    //$('#SearchInput').val(this.textContent);
  });
});


// in javascript

window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('div.region_dropdown_content a').forEach(function(ele, index) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      document.getElementById('SearchInput').value = this.textContent;
    });
  })
};
```

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: url(../images/background/body_background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo img{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.SearchSummoners {
  margin: auto;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid;

  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.region_dropdown_section {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.region_dropdown_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.region_dropdown_content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.region_dropdown_content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .region_dropdown_content {
  display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.Searchbox_Summoners {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
}

#SearchBox{
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left:  10%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 40px;;
}

#SearchInput{
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="logo">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&txt=500%C3%97225&w=500&h=225">
</div>
<div class="SearchSummoners">
    <div id="SearchBox">
        <form method="POST">
            <input id="SearchInput" value="Enter the Summoner Name"  onfocus="if(this.value  == 'Enter the Summoner Name') { this.value = ''; } " onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter the Summoner Name'; }"  type="text" name="SummonerName"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="region_dropdown_section">
        <button class="dropbtn">Select Region</button>
        <div class="region_dropdown_content">
            <a href="#">North America</a>
            <a href="#">Europe West</a>
            <a href="#">Europe NE</a>
            <a href="#">Korea</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, It works good, but the button has to change text. The region doesn't have to go in the search box.

Also the button needs to be in the searchbox on the right side like this: 
https://gyazo.com/8d2f642b02b7a0de0ebfa5ebf11dd74c

Thanks for the work! Sorry if I worded it wrong, my english is not good

Comment: @BPrepper Do not worry. Thanks a lot to be with us.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click',".region_dropdown_content a", function()
{
 var text = $(this).text();
 $(".dropbtn").text("");
  $(".dropbtn").text(text);
   $('#SearchInput').val(text);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery

You can give you anchors a class.

```
    <div class="region_dropdown_section">
      <button class="dropbtn">Select Region</button>
      <div class="region_dropdown_content">
        <a class="region" href="#">North America</a>
        <a class="region" href="#">Europe West</a>
        <a class="region" href="#">Europe NE</a>
        <a class="region" href="#">Korea</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If one of them is clicked on. Change the text of the button to the value of the anchor tag.

```
$('.region').click(function(){
  $('.dropbtn').html(this.text);
});
```